# <span class="typed"></span> there's a code within "typed" that I am trying to edit, how to?

Tags: html

There is code within "typed" that I am trying to edit and change. Within "typed" there is code that doesn't align with the project.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.typed').innerHTML = 'Goodbye World'; // <- this is what changes the content inside the HTML
}, 2000);
```

```html
<span class="typed">Hello World</span>
```

Using setTimeout just to add a delay to the change of content to show it works.

Targeting elements by classes is dangerous though in case there is more than 1 element using that class. It would be better to use id instead.